# Dictionary compatibility of base class vs. subclass values

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, dictionary

I have an object hierarchy:

```
MyObject
+Variable
+etc.
```

(So MyObject is the base class, and Variable is one of the subclasses).

I have the dictionaries for the specific types

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, Variable> variables 
    = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Variable>();
```

etc.

and I would like to put all the various lists in one high level dictionary, where I would find all the specific lists:

```
private Dictionary<Type, ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyObject>> objects 
    = new Dictionary<Type, ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyObject>>();
```

But I cannot add the specific dictionary to the high level dictionary:

```
objects.Add(typeof(Variable), variables); // DOES NOT COMPILE
```

Is there a means to do a what I want? I would not want to define the variables list as

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyObject> variables 
    = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyObject>(); // WORKS, BUT NOT NICE TO USE
```

So I want to use the specific lists to perform type specific operations, but also enable generic operations on all object types via the 'objects' dictionary, so that I don't need to code everything manually for each sub type.

For example, I would like to define a method like this:

```
    public List<Variable> GetVariables()
    {
        return variables.Values.ToList();
    }
```

So I could use Variable objects when I know that they are all variables.

Comment: When you add the item, you aren't adding a key with it. The `Add` method takes a key and a value. Do you want a dictionary of dictionaries, or a list of dictionaries? There is also attempted variance here that will fail I think.

Comment: Can you tell me what happens when you try to add the specific typed dictionary, what is the compiler error?

Comment: With your object hierarchy, do you mean that `Variable` is a class derived from `MyObject`?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the key. The key would be the type, so I could fetch the correct dictionary for the specific type.

Comment: @Philipp M, yes that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your example, what you are trying to accomplish is not possible since you are trying to add object of type `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Variable>` and object of type `ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyObject>` to the dictionary which has strong type as the second argument of `ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyObject>`. Therefore you can't add the objects of the first type. It would be like when you want to add `double` and `string` as the second argument to the `Dictionary<int, string>` object which is not possible.

But there is a workaround which might be doable. If all your types (`MyObject, Variable` etc.) derive from the same Interface than you could do something like this:

```
public interface MyInterface
{          
}

public class MyObject:MyInterface
{
}

public class Variable:MyInterface
{
}
```

Than you could call this code, similar to one you wanted. When you retrieve the dictionary you want you could cast your objects to the specific type or use common methods and polymorphism will serve its purpose.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyInterface> myClass1Dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyInterface>();
myClass1Dict.TryAdd("one", new MyObject());
myClass1Dict.TryAdd("two", new MyObject());
ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyInterface> myClass2Dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyInterface>();
myClass1Dict.TryAdd("one", new Variable());
myClass1Dict.TryAdd("two", new Variable());
ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyInterface>> objectDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ConcurrentDictionary<string, MyInterface>>();
objectDict.TryAdd(Type.GetType(MyObject), myClass1Dict);
objectDict.TryAdd(Type.GetType(Variable), myClass2Dict);
```

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure if this helps. With the classes, I can also define each dictionary as <Key, MyObject>. But I just need to cast between the specific types and MyObject, which I would like to avoid, when I know that I am dealing with specific objects.

Comment: Well if your classes have the same methods with different implementations (overrides) than you won't need to cast, that way you will be able to call the methods you want on the interface declared objects and polymorphism will do the rest (call the exact method). If your objects don't have anything in common than you could use Dictionary<Type, object> but you will have to cast those object into specific dictionaries. Either way, you will have to do some casting or redesign your classes or not use the Dictionary but simple ArrayList (or similar) and have some index type mapping.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the problem I tried to overcome. I would like to use the variables as variables, but also handle all my lists is a generic way with the same code.

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't possible, C# is a strongly typed language, you could do that with some script code but not here

Comment: That seems to be the conclusion. Thanks for the input.